# Inserting random values based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following DataFrame containing various information about a certain product. **Input3** is a list of sentences created as shown below:

```
sentence_list = (['Køb online her','Sammenlign priser her','Tjek priser fra 4 butikker','Se produkter fra 4 butikker', 'Stort udvalg fra 4 butikker','Sammenlign og køb'])
df["Input3"] = np.random.choice(sentence_list, size=len(df))
```

**Full_Input** is a string created by joining various columns, its content being something like: "ProductName from Brand - Buy online here - Sitename". It is created like this:

```
df["Full_Input"] = df['TitleTag'].astype(str) +  " " + df['Input2'].astype(str) + " " + df['Input3'].astype(str) + " " +  df['Input4'].astype(str) + " " +  df['Input5'].astype(str)
```

[image]

The problem here is that **Full_Input_Length** should be under 55. Therefore I am trying to figure out how to put a condition while randomly generating **Input3** so when it adds up with the other columns' strings, the full input length does not go over 55.

This is what I tried:

```
for col in range(len(df)):
    condlist = [df["Full_Input"].apply(len) < 55]
    choicelist = [sentence_list]
    df['Input3_OK'][col] = np.random.choice.select(condlist, choicelist)
```

As expected, it doesn't work like that. `np.random.choice.select` is not a thing and I am getting an AttributeError.

How can I do that instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are guaranteed to have at least one item in `Input3` that will satisfy this condition, you may want to try something like conditioning your random selection ONLY on values in your `sentence_list` that would be of an acceptable length:

```py
# convert to series to enable use of pandas filtering mechanism:
my_sentences = [s for s in sentence_list if len(s) < MAX_LENGTH]

# randomly select from this filtered list:
np.random.choice(my_sentences)
```

In other words, perform the filter on each list of strings BEFORE you call `random.choice`.

You can run this for each row in a dataframe like so:

```py
def choose_string(full_input):
    return np.random.choice([
        s 
        for s in sentence_list 
        if len(s) + len(full_input) < 55
    ])

df["Input3_OK"] = df.Full_Input.map(choose_string)
```