# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'size'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

This is kind of related to my previous question, unanswered, from here:[Inserting random values based on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57887968/inserting-random-values-based-on-condition)

```
for row in range(len(df)):
    while df["Full_Input_Length"][row] >= 55:
        df["Input3"][row] = np.random.choice(sentence_list, size=len(df))
        df["Full_Input"][row] = np.array2string(df['TitleTag'][row]).replace("'","") +  " " + np.array2string(df['Input2'][row]).replace("'","") + " " + np.array2string(df['Input3'][row]).replace("'","") + " " +  np.array2string(df['Input4'][row]).replace("'","") + " " +  np.array2string(df['Input5'][row]).replace("'","") 
        df["Full_Input_Length"][row] = len(df["Full_Input"][row])
    break
```

I stuck to my initial plan and continued my attempts to write down this for loop properly. The error I am getting is on line 4, where it says

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'size'

Basically I am trying to concatenate multiple strings into column Full_Input. I would assume that now the problem is at `df["Full_Input"][row]` but I am not quite sure how to write it properly so my code would run. I tried different ways but none worked - other errors popped up.

What am I getting wrong? Is there any other way of doing this?

**Full code:**

```
    df['TitleTag'] = np.nan
for col in range(len(df)):
    condlist = [df['BrandId'][col] != 2, df['BrandId'][col] == 2]
    choicelist = [df['Name'][col] + ' fra ' + df['BrandName'][col], df['Name'][col]]
    df['TitleTag'][col] = np.select(condlist, choicelist)

df['Input1'] = np.nan
for col in range(len(df)):
    condlist = [df['BrandId'][col] != 2, df['BrandId'][col] == 2]
    choicelist = [df['Name'][col] + ' fra ' + df['BrandName'][col], np.nan]
    df['Input1'][col] = np.select(condlist, choicelist)

symbol_list = (['-','=>','|','->'])
df["Input2"] = np.random.choice(symbol_list, size=len(df))

sentence_list = (['Køb online her','Sammenlign priser her','Tjek priser fra 4 butikker','Se produkter fra 4 butikker', 'Stort udvalg fra 4 butikker','Sammenlign og køb'])
df["Input3"] = np.random.choice(sentence_list, size=len(df))


symbol_list2 = (['-','|'])
df["Input4"] = np.random.choice(symbol_list2, size=len(df))

df["Input5"] = "Site.dk"

df["Full_Input"] = df['TitleTag'].astype(str) +  " " + df['Input2'].astype(str) + " " + df['Input3'].astype(str) + " " +  df['Input4'].astype(str) + " " +  df['Input5'].astype(str) 
df["Full_Input_Length"] = df["Full_Input"].apply(len)
for col in range(len(df)):
    while df["Full_Input_Length"][col] >= 55:
        df["Input3"][col] = np.random.choice(sentence_list, size=len(df))
        df["Full_Input"][col] = np.array2string(df['TitleTag'][col]).replace("'","") +  " " + np.array2string(df['Input2'][col]).replace("'","") + " " + np.array2string(df['Input3'][col]).replace("'","") + " " +  np.array2string(df['Input4'][col]).replace("'","") + " " +  np.array2string(df['Input5'][col]).replace("'","") 
        df["Full_Input_Length"][col] = len(df["Full_Input"][col])
        break
```

Comment: what does `df['TitleTag'][row]` and other variables which you are concatenating looks like?

Comment: `df['TitleTag'][1]
Out[179]: array('Mineslunder m. ramsløg øko. fra Mineslund', dtype='<U41')` and all of them are of this type.

Comment: `In[181]: np.array2string(df['TitleTag'][col]).replace("'","")
Out[181]: 'Mineslunder m. ramsløg øko. fra Mineslund'` separately they also work well

Comment: if it separately works fine, then error is not on that line of the code. probably if you could paste stack trace and more code then it would be helpful.

Comment: I just noticed that the problem occurs when I try to concatenate them. For example: `np.array2string(df['TitleTag'][col]).replace("'","") + np.array2string(df['Input2'][col]).replace("'","")` . I will edit the original post with the full code.

Comment: what about the stack trace?

Comment: Right, forgot about it: `File "<ipython-input-182-d217ea7ec635>", line 1, in <module>
    np.array2string(df['TitleTag'][col]).replace("'","") + np.array2string(df['Input2'][col]).replace("'","")

  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\arrayprint.py", line 687, in array2string
    if a.size == 0:`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199317/discussion-between-vbrises-and-questieme).

Comment: Looks like `df['Input2'][col]` is a string rather than an array.  `str(df[...])` would handle both arrays and strings.  But maybe you should first determine why this selection is string, were as the code assumes it will be an array.

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?